# How to use factory/service which makes an Ajax request in ui-router resolve?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router

I am using the ui-router(http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) solution for a form wizard and my state configuration looks like the following:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('TabsView', {
     url: '/mcm/:mcmcid',
     controller: 'TabsController',
     templateUrl: 'ngapps/mcm/views/TabsView.html'
  })
  .state('TabsView.Campaign Info', {
     url: '/campaign-info',
     templateUrl: 'ngapps/mcm/views/Campaign Info.html',
     resolve: {
       campaignFactory: 'CampaignFactory',
       campaignData: function($stateParams,campaignFactory) {
                       return campaignFactory.getCampaignInfo($stateParams.mcmcid).$service;
                     }
     },
     controller: 'CampaignInfoController'
  });
```

For the state "TabsView.Campaign Info" I try to resolve the campaignData by calling the CampaignFactory. The code for Campaign Factoy is as follows:

```
marketingCampaignModule.factory("CampaignFactory", ['AjaxFactory', '$q', function(AjaxFactory, $q) {
    return {
        getCampaignInfo: function(mcmcid) {
            var result = {empty: true};
            if (mcmcid > 0) {
                var ajaxPromise = AjaxFactory.post("index.php/mcm/infosave/view", {mcmcid: mcmcid});
                ajaxPromise.then(function(data) {
                    if (data['success']) {
                        if (data['params']) {
                            result = {'name': data['params']['name'], 'description': data['params']['description']};
                        }
                    }
                    return result;
                });
            }
        }
    };

}]);
```

campaignData in resolve does not get resolved. But I see that a call to the getCampaignInfo function of the CampaignFactory is being made in the console. I know I am doing something wrong with promise.Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

As per Chandermani's comment I modified the factory to return a promise as follows:

```
marketingCampaignModule.factory("CampaignFactory", ['AjaxFactory', '$q', function(AjaxFactory, $q) {
    return {
        getCampaignInfo: function(mcmcid) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var result = {empty: true};
            if (mcmcid > 0) {
                var ajaxPromise = AjaxFactory.post("index.php/mcm/infosave/view", {mcmcid: mcmcid});
                ajaxPromise.then(function(data) {
                    if (data['success']) {
                        if (data['params']) {
                            result = {'name': data['params']['name'], 'description': data['params']['description']};
                        }
                    }
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                });
            }else{
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };

}]);
```

And modifed the resolve as follows:

```
resolve: {
                  campaignFactory: 'CampaignFactory',
                  campaignData: function($stateParams,campaignFactory) {
                      campaignFactory.getCampaignInfo($stateParams.mcmcid).then(function(data){
                          return data;
                      });
                  }
              }
```

Still doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to return a promise from the getCampaignInfo method. And somewhere in the callback use the defer api to resolve it. Read about $q service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the update you have done, you are just missing the return statement in resolve

```
 campaignData: function($stateParams,campaignFactory) {
                   return  campaignFactory.getCampaignInfo($stateParams.mcmcid);
                  }
```